# .BAT to execute command of another .bat as if executed per "current folder - open cmd window here"?

Tags: windows, batch

I'm unsure if there is a solid method to automate these steps with a batch file*
*(the for this batch file would be a)

a)
in this folder I run cmd.exe with Shift + Open command window here

b) and execute

```
cmd /k cd <path to bat2.bat>
bat2.bat --<run command for it>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
cmd.exe /k "cd <setpathhere> && bat2.bat --<run command for it>"
```